# Get icons for common file types

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, icons

I want to get the icons of common file types in my dll. I am using vc++. I only have the file extension and mime type of the file based on which I want to get the icon for the file.

Can someone please tell me how I can do that? (The method available in vc++ needs the user to give the path of the file for which the icon is needed. I do not have access to any such file)

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Shell API

You can get them from the shell by calling [`SHGetFileInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(VS.85).aspx) along with the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag - this flag allows the routine to work without requiring the filename passed in to actually exist, so if you have a file extension just make up a filename, append the extension, and pass it in.

By combining other flags, you'll be able to retrieve:

- **A large or small icon as determined by the system configuration**: `SHGFI_ICON|SHGFI_LARGEICON` or `SHGFI_ICON|SHGFI_SMALLICON`
- **A large or small icon as determined by the shell configuration**: `SHGFI_ICON|SHGFI_LARGEICON|SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE` or `SHGFI_ICON|SHGFI_SMALLICON|SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE`
- **The index of the icon in the shell's image list** along with the appropriate image list: `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX`
- **The path and filename of the actual module where the icon is stored** (along with the icon index in that module): `SHGFI_ICONLOCATION`

#### Examples

```
// Load a System Large icon image
SHGetFileInfo( szFileName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &shfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), 
   SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON);

// Load a System Small icon image
SHGetFileInfo( szFileName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &shfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), 
   SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON);

// Load a Shell Large icon image
SHGetFileInfo( szFileName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &shfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), 
   SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE);

// Load a Shell Small icon image
SHGetFileInfo( szFileName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &shfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), 
   SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES 
   | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
```

If you want to draw such an icon, use something like this:

```
// Draw it at its native size
DrawIconEx( hDC, nLeft, nTop, hIcon, 0, 0, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL );

// Draw it at the System Large size
DrawIconEx( hDC, nLeft, nTop, hIcon, 0, 0, 0, 
            NULL, DI_DEFAULTSIZE | DI_NORMAL );

// Draw it at some other size (40x40 in this example)
DrawIconEx( hDC, nLeft, nTop, hIcon, 40, 40, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL );
```

The icon handle as well as the file system path can be obtained from the `SHFILEINFO` structure:

```
typedef struct _SHFILEINFOA
{
        HICON       hIcon;                      // out: icon
        int         iIcon;                      // out: icon index
        DWORD       dwAttributes;               // out: SFGAO_ flags
        CHAR        szDisplayName[MAX_PATH];    // out: display name (or path)
        CHAR        szTypeName[80];             // out: type name
} SHFILEINFOA;
```

Keep in mind that you must free the obtained icon by passing `hIcon` to [`DestroyIcon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648063(VS.85).aspx) after you're done with it.

Comment: @jn: I liked your examples, so i combined our answers and removed mine.

Answer (score -3):

Identify the icon information from the registry, the associate file type and program that handles the file and extract the icon from the file.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/iconextract.aspx

Comment: Bad idea - such things may change between Windows versions. Stick to the documented interface.