# How do I get common file type icons in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, icons, file-type

As seen in [This SO question on getting icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524137/get-icons-for-common-file-types) for common file types, it's quite possible for a windows program to get the icons for a registered file type using the C++ Shell API.  These icons may or may not exist on disk - for example, we wanted to make our own custom file browser and want to display the system-associated icon with the file.

Is there a native C# way to get the icons for various file types (and if so, how) or must it be done through PInvoke with shell API?

And as a follow up, if there is a native .NET way of doing it, is there a cross-platform way of doing it?

Comment: Just Refer to this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetFileTypeAndIcon.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at: http://mvolo.com/display-pretty-file-icons-in-your-aspnet-applications-with-iconhandler/

It's not the cleanest solution but it works. Otherwise, try to get your hands on a library of Icons that's based on mime type or file extension.

Comment: His 2.0 version of it looks even more interesting.  Too bad it seems the only solutions involve p/invoke.

Comment: Link broken. Getting 403 forbidden. try http://mvolo.com/display-pretty-file-icons-in-your-aspnet-applications-with-iconhandler/

Answer (score 39):

One of my old open source project include an [Icon class](http://win32iam.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/win32iam/trunk/BlackFox.UninstallInformations/IconHandler.cs?view=markup) that does exactly that, feel free to rip it, seeing the age I put this file in the public domain anyway it's just PInvoke for most part.

To get an icon you use for example :

```
Icon zipIcon = BlackFox.Win32.Icons.IconFromExtension(".zip", SystemIconSize.Small);
```

Full sample :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BlackFox.Win32;
using System.Drawing;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PictureBox pict = new PictureBox();
        pict.Image = Icons.IconFromExtension(".zip", Icons.SystemIconSize.Large).ToBitmap();
        pict.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;

        Form form = new Form();
        form.Controls.Add(pict);

        Application.Run(form);        
    }
}
```

The library :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BlackFox.Win32
{
    public static class Icons
    {
        #region Custom exceptions class

        public class IconNotFoundException : Exception
        {
            public IconNotFoundException(string fileName, int index)
                : base(string.Format("Icon with Id = {0} wasn't found in file {1}", index, fileName))
            {
            }
        }

        public class UnableToExtractIconsException : Exception
        {
            public UnableToExtractIconsException(string fileName, int firstIconIndex, int iconCount)
                : base(string.Format("Tryed to extract {2} icons starting from the one with id {1} from the \"{0}\" file but failed", fileName, firstIconIndex, iconCount))
            {
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region DllImports

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains information about a file object. 
        /// </summary>
        struct SHFILEINFO
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Handle to the icon that represents the file. You are responsible for
            /// destroying this handle with DestroyIcon when you no longer need it. 
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr hIcon;

            /// <summary>
            /// Index of the icon image within the system image list.
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr iIcon;

            /// <summary>
            /// Array of values that indicates the attributes of the file object.
            /// For information about these values, see the IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf
            /// method.
            /// </summary>
            public uint dwAttributes;

            /// <summary>
            /// String that contains the name of the file as it appears in the Microsoft
            /// Windows Shell, or the path and file name of the file that contains the
            /// icon representing the file.
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string szDisplayName;

            /// <summary>
            /// String that describes the type of file.
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
            public string szTypeName;
        };

        [Flags]
        enum FileInfoFlags : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieve the handle to the icon that represents the file and the index 
            /// of the icon within the system image list. The handle is copied to the 
            /// hIcon member of the structure specified by psfi, and the index is copied 
            /// to the iIcon member.
            /// </summary>
            SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100,
            /// <summary>
            /// Indicates that the function should not attempt to access the file 
            /// specified by pszPath. Rather, it should act as if the file specified by 
            /// pszPath exists with the file attributes passed in dwFileAttributes.
            /// </summary>
            SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Creates an array of handles to large or small icons extracted from
        ///     the specified executable file, dynamic-link library (DLL), or icon
        ///     file. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpszFile">
        ///     Name of an executable file, DLL, or icon file from which icons will
        ///     be extracted.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="nIconIndex">
        ///     <para>
        ///         Specifies the zero-based index of the first icon to extract. For
        ///         example, if this value is zero, the function extracts the first
        ///         icon in the specified file.
        ///     </para>
        ///     <para>
        ///         If this value is �1 and <paramref name="phiconLarge"/> and
        ///         <paramref name="phiconSmall"/> are both NULL, the function returns
        ///         the total number of icons in the specified file. If the file is an
        ///         executable file or DLL, the return value is the number of
        ///         RT_GROUP_ICON resources. If the file is an .ico file, the return
        ///         value is 1. 
        ///     </para>
        ///     <para>
        ///         Windows 95/98/Me, Windows NT 4.0 and later: If this value is a 
        ///         negative number and either <paramref name="phiconLarge"/> or 
        ///         <paramref name="phiconSmall"/> is not NULL, the function begins by
        ///         extracting the icon whose resource identifier is equal to the
        ///         absolute value of <paramref name="nIconIndex"/>. For example, use -3
        ///         to extract the icon whose resource identifier is 3. 
        ///     </para>
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="phIconLarge">
        ///     An array of icon handles that receives handles to the large icons
        ///     extracted from the file. If this parameter is NULL, no large icons
        ///     are extracted from the file.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="phIconSmall">
        ///     An array of icon handles that receives handles to the small icons
        ///     extracted from the file. If this parameter is NULL, no small icons
        ///     are extracted from the file. 
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="nIcons">
        ///     Specifies the number of icons to extract from the file. 
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     If the <paramref name="nIconIndex"/> parameter is -1, the
        ///     <paramref name="phIconLarge"/> parameter is NULL, and the
        ///     <paramref name="phiconSmall"/> parameter is NULL, then the return
        ///     value is the number of icons contained in the specified file.
        ///     Otherwise, the return value is the number of icons successfully
        ///     extracted from the file. 
        /// </returns>
        [DllImport("Shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        extern static int ExtractIconEx(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] 
            string lpszFile,
            int nIconIndex,
            IntPtr[] phIconLarge,
            IntPtr[] phIconSmall,
            int nIcons);

        [DllImport("Shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        extern static IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
            string pszPath,
            int dwFileAttributes,
            out SHFILEINFO psfi,
            int cbFileInfo,
            FileInfoFlags uFlags);

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Two constants extracted from the FileInfoFlags, the only that are
        /// meaningfull for the user of this class.
        /// </summary>
        public enum SystemIconSize : int
        {
            Large = 0x000000000,
            Small = 0x000000001
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the number of icons in the specified file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Full path of the file to look for.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static int GetIconsCountInFile(string fileName)
        {
            return ExtractIconEx(fileName, -1, null, null, 0);
        }

        #region ExtractIcon-like functions

        public static void ExtractEx(string fileName, List<Icon> largeIcons,
            List<Icon> smallIcons, int firstIconIndex, int iconCount)
        {
            /*
             * Memory allocations
             */

            IntPtr[] smallIconsPtrs = null;
            IntPtr[] largeIconsPtrs = null;

            if (smallIcons != null)
            {
                smallIconsPtrs = new IntPtr[iconCount];
            }
            if (largeIcons != null)
            {
                largeIconsPtrs = new IntPtr[iconCount];
            }

            /*
             * Call to native Win32 API
             */

            int apiResult = ExtractIconEx(fileName, firstIconIndex, largeIconsPtrs, smallIconsPtrs, iconCount);
            if (apiResult != iconCount)
            {
                throw new UnableToExtractIconsException(fileName, firstIconIndex, iconCount);
            }

            /*
             * Fill lists
             */

            if (smallIcons != null)
            {
                smallIcons.Clear();
                foreach (IntPtr actualIconPtr in smallIconsPtrs)
                {
                    smallIcons.Add(Icon.FromHandle(actualIconPtr));
                }
            }
            if (largeIcons != null)
            {
                largeIcons.Clear();
                foreach (IntPtr actualIconPtr in largeIconsPtrs)
                {
                    largeIcons.Add(Icon.FromHandle(actualIconPtr));
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<Icon> ExtractEx(string fileName, SystemIconSize size,
            int firstIconIndex, int iconCount)
        {
            List<Icon> iconList = new List<Icon>();

            switch (size)
            {
                case SystemIconSize.Large:
                    ExtractEx(fileName, iconList, null, firstIconIndex, iconCount);
                    break;

                case SystemIconSize.Small:
                    ExtractEx(fileName, null, iconList, firstIconIndex, iconCount);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");
            }

            return iconList;
        }

        public static void Extract(string fileName, List<Icon> largeIcons, List<Icon> smallIcons)
        {
            int iconCount = GetIconsCountInFile(fileName);
            ExtractEx(fileName, largeIcons, smallIcons, 0, iconCount);
        }

        public static List<Icon> Extract(string fileName, SystemIconSize size)
        {
            int iconCount = GetIconsCountInFile(fileName);
            return ExtractEx(fileName, size, 0, iconCount);
        }

        public static Icon ExtractOne(string fileName, int index, SystemIconSize size)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Icon> iconList = ExtractEx(fileName, size, index, 1);
                return iconList[0];            
            }
            catch (UnableToExtractIconsException)
            {
                throw new IconNotFoundException(fileName, index);
            }
        }

        public static void ExtractOne(string fileName, int index,
            out Icon largeIcon, out Icon smallIcon)
        {
            List<Icon> smallIconList = new List<Icon>();
            List<Icon> largeIconList = new List<Icon>();
            try
            {
                ExtractEx(fileName, largeIconList, smallIconList, index, 1);
                largeIcon = largeIconList[0];
                smallIcon = smallIconList[0];
            }
            catch (UnableToExtractIconsException)
            {
                throw new IconNotFoundException(fileName, index);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        //this will look throw the registry 
        //to find if the Extension have an icon.
        public static Icon IconFromExtension(string extension,
                                                SystemIconSize size)
        {
            // Add the '.' to the extension if needed
            if (extension[0] != '.') extension = '.' + extension;

            //opens the registry for the wanted key.
            RegistryKey Root = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            RegistryKey ExtensionKey = Root.OpenSubKey(extension);
            ExtensionKey.GetValueNames();
            RegistryKey ApplicationKey =
                Root.OpenSubKey(ExtensionKey.GetValue("").ToString());

            //gets the name of the file that have the icon.
            string IconLocation =
                ApplicationKey.OpenSubKey("DefaultIcon").GetValue("").ToString();
            string[] IconPath = IconLocation.Split(',');

            if (IconPath[1] == null) IconPath[1] = "0";
            IntPtr[] Large = new IntPtr[1], Small = new IntPtr[1];

            //extracts the icon from the file.
            ExtractIconEx(IconPath[0],
                Convert.ToInt16(IconPath[1]), Large, Small, 1);
            return size == SystemIconSize.Large ?
                Icon.FromHandle(Large[0]) : Icon.FromHandle(Small[0]);
        }

        public static Icon IconFromExtensionShell(string extension, SystemIconSize size)
        {
            //add '.' if nessesry
            if (extension[0] != '.') extension = '.' + extension;

            //temp struct for getting file shell info
            SHFILEINFO fileInfo = new SHFILEINFO();

            SHGetFileInfo(
                extension,
                0,
                out fileInfo,
                Marshal.SizeOf(fileInfo),
                FileInfoFlags.SHGFI_ICON | FileInfoFlags.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | (FileInfoFlags)size);

            return Icon.FromHandle(fileInfo.hIcon);
        }

        public static Icon IconFromResource(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

            return new Icon(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parse strings in registry who contains the name of the icon and
        /// the index of the icon an return both parts.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="regString">The full string in the form "path,index" as found in registry.</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">The "path" part of the string.</param>
        /// <param name="index">The "index" part of the string.</param>
        public static void ExtractInformationsFromRegistryString(
            string regString, out string fileName, out int index)
        {
            if (regString == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("regString");
            }
            if (regString.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The string should not be empty.", "regString");
            }

            index = 0;
            string[] strArr = regString.Replace("\"", "").Split(',');
            fileName = strArr[0].Trim();
            if (strArr.Length > 1)
            {
                int.TryParse(strArr[1].Trim(), out index);
            }
        }

        public static Icon ExtractFromRegistryString(string regString, SystemIconSize size)
        {
            string fileName;
            int index;
            ExtractInformationsFromRegistryString(regString, out fileName, out index);
            return ExtractOne(fileName, index, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seem that SO handle pretty well copy pasta of full .cs file, interesting to know.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: Are you implying that it's spaghetti code?  (*groans*)

Comment: @Daniel: No ^_^ just that it's just a big copy/paste of a full file :D  and SO seem to take it, color it and display it without problem.

Comment: Of course, the only problem with this is it isn't a .NET only solution...you have to use pInvoke.  :(  But hey, it works :)

Comment: Well the Icon -> Bitmap par could be made into pure-C# with a .ico file parser but the operating system is providing this for free and in a perfectly usable fashion (as long as you are targeting a windows platform, but then why use a .ico elsewhere).

Comment: Regarding the extension -> icon part Microsoft discourage from querying the registry directly as they could (an already did with WoW64) change it between versions or Service Packs while the API offered by the shell shouldn't change. The pInvoke is then pretty natural to call the shell as there is no managed interface to the shell included in windows (or any other big OS).

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you have already found a solution for your problems but for the benefit of others i have made some modifications to VirtualBlackFox's solution.

Just replace the IconFromExtension method...

```
public static Icon IconFromExtension(string extension,
                                            SystemIconSize size)
    {
        // Add the '.' to the extension if needed
        if (extension[0] != '.') extension = '.' + extension;

        //opens the registry for the wanted key.
        RegistryKey Root = Registry.ClassesRoot;
        RegistryKey ExtensionKey = Root.OpenSubKey(extension);
        ExtensionKey.GetValueNames();
        RegistryKey ApplicationKey =
            Root.OpenSubKey(ExtensionKey.GetValue("").ToString());

        RegistryKey CurrentVer = null;
        try
        {
            CurrentVer = Root.OpenSubKey(ApplicationKey.OpenSubKey("CurVer").GetValue("").ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //current version not found... carry on without it?
        }

        if (CurrentVer != null)
            ApplicationKey = CurrentVer;

        //gets the name of the file that have the icon.
        string IconLocation =
            ApplicationKey.OpenSubKey("DefaultIcon").GetValue("").ToString();
        string[] IconPath = IconLocation.Split(',');


        IntPtr[] Large = null;
        IntPtr[] Small = null;
        int iIconPathNumber = 0;

        if (IconPath.Length > 1)
            iIconPathNumber = 1;
        else
            iIconPathNumber = 0;


        if (IconPath[iIconPathNumber] == null) IconPath[iIconPathNumber] = "0";
        Large = new IntPtr[1];
        Small = new IntPtr[1];



        //extracts the icon from the file.
        if (iIconPathNumber > 0)
        {
            ExtractIconEx(IconPath[0],
                Convert.ToInt16(IconPath[iIconPathNumber]), Large, Small, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            ExtractIconEx(IconPath[0],
                Convert.ToInt16(0), Large, Small, 1);
        }


        return size == SystemIconSize.Large ?
            Icon.FromHandle(Large[0]) : Icon.FromHandle(Small[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon() 
won't do the trick. As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx) states it only extracts icons **contained** in the file. So creating dummy files won't help either. To my best knowledge you have to go the p/invoke way to get to these icons. A question related to this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell). [MaLio](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/malio/archive/2004/10/04/27603.aspx) seems to have a quite complete example of how to get the icons with p/invoke.

I don't know of a platform agnostic way to do this either (and I don't think there is one).

Sorry i couldn't provide you with better news!

Comment: Thanks for the unfortunate news.  :)

Comment: Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(...) works fine for me at getting the associated icon of any file (not just DLLs or EXEs). Not sure what adyp's problem was, but maybe the method improved since then.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of browsing through registry, one may use the [IQueryAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761400.aspx) interface. This interface can also be used to get more information about registered file types (see i.e. ASSOCSTR type). Below I attach code which replaces IconFromExtension method from VirtualBlackFox's solution (parts of his code are left untouched):

```
public static Icon IconFromExtension(string extension, SystemIconSize size)
{
    if (extension[0] != '.') extension = '.' + extension;

    object obj;
    shell.AssocCreate(shell.CLSID_QueryAssociations, ref shell.IID_IQueryAssociations, out obj);
    var qa = (shell.IQueryAssociations)obj;
    qa.Init(shell.ASSOCF.INIT_DEFAULTTOSTAR, Convert.ToString(extension), UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    var bufSize = 0;
    qa.GetString(shell.ASSOCF.NOTRUNCATE, shell.ASSOCSTR.DEFAULTICON, null, null, ref bufSize);

    var sb = new StringBuilder(bufSize);
    qa.GetString(shell.ASSOCF.NOTRUNCATE, shell.ASSOCSTR.DEFAULTICON, null, sb, ref bufSize);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
    {
        var iconLocation = sb.ToString();
        var iconPath = iconLocation.Split(',');

        var iIconPathNumber = iconPath.Length > 1 ? 1 : 0;

        if (iconPath[iIconPathNumber] == null) iconPath[iIconPathNumber] = "0";
        var large = new IntPtr[1];
        var small = new IntPtr[1];

        //extracts the icon from the file.
        ExtractIconEx(iconPath[0],
                      iIconPathNumber > 0 ? Convert.ToInt16(iconPath[iIconPathNumber]) : Convert.ToInt16(0),
                      large,
                      small, 1);

        return size == SystemIconSize.Large
                  ? Icon.FromHandle(large[0])
                  : Icon.FromHandle(small[0]);
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

In addition to the above code one needs "shell" class - a wrapper of Shell API (below it is limited to AssocCreate and necessary types):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
#pragma warning disable 1591
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

namespace <put_your_appropriate_namespace_here>
{
   public class shell
   {
      [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
      public extern static int AssocCreate(
         Guid clsid,
         ref Guid riid,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppv);

      [Flags]
      public enum ASSOCF
      {
         INIT_NOREMAPCLSID = 0x00000001,
         INIT_BYEXENAME = 0x00000002,
         OPEN_BYEXENAME = 0x00000002,
         INIT_DEFAULTTOSTAR = 0x00000004,
         INIT_DEFAULTTOFOLDER = 0x00000008,
         NOUSERSETTINGS = 0x00000010,
         NOTRUNCATE = 0x00000020,
         VERIFY = 0x00000040,
         REMAPRUNDLL = 0x00000080,
         NOFIXUPS = 0x00000100,
         IGNOREBASECLASS = 0x00000200,
         INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN = 0x00000400
      }

      public enum ASSOCSTR
      {
         COMMAND = 1,
         EXECUTABLE,
         FRIENDLYDOCNAME,
         FRIENDLYAPPNAME,
         NOOPEN,
         SHELLNEWVALUE,
         DDECOMMAND,
         DDEIFEXEC,
         DDEAPPLICATION,
         DDETOPIC,
         INFOTIP,
         QUICKTIP,
         TILEINFO,
         CONTENTTYPE,
         DEFAULTICON,
         SHELLEXTENSION
      }

      public enum ASSOCKEY
      {
         SHELLEXECCLASS = 1,
         APP,
         CLASS,
         BASECLASS
      }

      public enum ASSOCDATA
      {
         MSIDESCRIPTOR = 1,
         NOACTIVATEHANDLER,
         QUERYCLASSSTORE,
         HASPERUSERASSOC,
         EDITFLAGS,
         VALUE
      }

      [Guid("c46ca590-3c3f-11d2-bee6-0000f805ca57"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
      public interface IQueryAssociations
      {
         void Init(
           [In] ASSOCF flags,
           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszAssoc,
           [In] UIntPtr hkProgid,
           [In] IntPtr hwnd);

         void GetString(
           [In] ASSOCF flags,
           [In] ASSOCSTR str,
           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszExtra,
           [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszOut,
           [In, Out] ref int pcchOut);

         void GetKey(
           [In] ASSOCF flags,
           [In] ASSOCKEY str,
           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszExtra,
           [Out] out UIntPtr phkeyOut);

         void GetData(
           [In] ASSOCF flags,
           [In] ASSOCDATA data,
           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszExtra,
           [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4)] out byte[] pvOut,
           [In, Out] ref int pcbOut);

         void GetEnum(); // not used actually
      }

      public static Guid CLSID_QueryAssociations = new Guid("a07034fd-6caa-4954-ac3f-97a27216f98a");
      public static Guid IID_IQueryAssociations = new Guid("c46ca590-3c3f-11d2-bee6-0000f805ca57");

   }
}
```

For WPF users, who need ImageSource:

Replace the return type from Icon to ImageSource and the return clause to:

```
var iconPtr = size == SystemIconSize.Large ? large[0] : small[0];
if (iconPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        iconPtr,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This class should do the job. Pass either a filename (with path) or folder name (with path).

```
public static class FileIcon
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public IntPtr iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };
    private const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
    private const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0; // 'Large icon
    private const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1; // 'Small icon

    public static System.Drawing.Icon GetLargeIcon(string file)
    {
        FileIcon.SHFILEINFO shinfo = new FileIcon.SHFILEINFO();
        IntPtr hImgLarge = FileIcon.SHGetFileInfo(file, 0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), FileIcon.SHGFI_ICON | FileIcon.SHGFI_LARGEICON);
        return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Icon GetSmallIcon(string file)
    {
        FileIcon.SHFILEINFO shinfo = new FileIcon.SHFILEINFO();
        IntPtr hImgLarge = FileIcon.SHGetFileInfo(file, 0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), FileIcon.SHGFI_ICON | FileIcon.SHGFI_SMALLICON);
        return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very compact!  Unfortunately it still doesn't do it with just C# libraries. (