# Getting FatalExecutionEngineError in c#?

Tags: c#, exception, clr, system.data.sqlite, objectlistview

Getting following exception at random positions.

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x65c08447, on thread 0x14d8. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

This module is worked fine yesterday but giving this exception today. i just changed debug configuration to x86. Yesterday it was AnyCPU. But i'm using sqlite and it reports following warning when configuration was AnyCPU.

> Warning   :- There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86".
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your project through the
>   Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

I'm using unmanaged code from [How do I get common file type icons in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616947/1273550). Also i'm using [objectlistview](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).
All the code except this is just for accessing database.
my machine has windows 7 x64 ultimate.

Error starting to come up in search functionality of my application

Comment: Sounds like you have x86-specific code in there which isn't working on x64.

Comment: I figured out the problem and it's fix is described in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034552/getting-exceptions-on-x86-system-when-using-unmanaged-code-to-get-file-icon-usin