# WinRT: Extract the Icon Associated with a File?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, icons, thumbnails, uwp

How do I get the image associated to a specific file (not thumbnail) in WinRT Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution I found yesterday, too. But with `ThumbnailMode.Music` you get the Icon with the backgroundcolor of the app.

Finally I found, that with `ThumbnailMode.SingleItem` I get a better result without background. So first I create an empty file with the right file extension and then I try to get the thumbnail:

```
string filename = "_tmp_ext" + fileextension;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = 
  await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(
    filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail thumb = 
  await file.GetThumbnailAsync(FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 
    16, FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);
if (thumb != null) {
  BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
  bitmapImage.SetSource(thumb.CloneStream());
  /* ... */
}
```

Any other solutions without creating a dummy file?

Comment: You could also check the best answer to this question. It requires p/invoke to the shell APIs, but who knows - maybe it'd work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616718/how-do-i-get-common-file-type-icons-in-c

Comment: This will only work for Side-Loading-Applications without App-Certification.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [Guidelines for thumbnails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465350.aspx) it seems like `ThumbnailMode.Music` might give you an icon when used with [`StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227213.aspx) for most file types - except music files that have an associated album art, although I'd hope to see a more robust way to get just the icon. Various MSDN Forums threads seem to indicate though that `GetThumbnailAsync()` IS the way to go.