# Get file icon from extension only, without existing

Tags: c#, windows

On Windows we would like to access the icon associated with a file type, i.e `.mp3`. However, from what I can tell there is only this method: `ExtractAssociatedIcon`[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon?view=netframework-4.7.2) which requires the file to exists. 
So can I get access to the icons somehow ?

Comment: Yes, but I warn you it won't be easy. As you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524137/get-icons-for-common-file-types) you can call a [shell function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa) to get the icon associated with a file extension without requiring an actual file. However you need to use PInvoke to call this from managed code  - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599235/how-do-i-fetch-the-folder-icon-on-windows-7-using-shell32-shgetfileinfo) shows a partial example.

Comment: … a bit of [searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C%23+SHGetFileInfo+icon&t=ffab&ia=qa) might find you something you can use.

Comment: @stuartd and I found a lot of answers where it said it didn't work

Comment: If it didn't work, then it wasn't being called correctly.

Comment: _"ExtractAssociatedIcon requires the file to exists"_ - yes it does, but **it does not have to be valid for the file type** - you can create a temporary text file called "textfile.mp3" and `ExtractAssociatedIcon` will return you the correct icon.